# @TableGenerator doesn't work with H2?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using H2 for testing environment my app. I have table Order and i would like start order id from 10000. I created Table Column:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "ORDER_GEN",
              table = "ID_GEN",
              pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
              valueColumnName = "SEQ_NUMBER",
              pkColumnValue = "ORDER_GEN",
              initialValue = 1000)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ORDER_GEN")
private Long orderId;
```

but doesn't work. I restarted app, table ID_GEN was created but order each time starting from 0.

Any ideas ?

Regards

Comment: "doesn't work". which means what? Some exception? some SQL is invoked ?

Comment: I mean, table ID_GEN was created but order each time starting from 0, not from 1000 (but should).

Comment: so post the precise SQL statements issued by your JPA provider when you call `em.persist`

Comment: Just repository.save(order) because i'm using Spring Data Rest. I've changed DB from H2 to MySQL and still doesn't work.

Comment: So you are using Spring Data JPA (!= JPA API). The JPA providers log tells you the SQL, so look at it. aka debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315956/5877109
The problem is with hibernate bug.

After added setting to application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

everything works very well.